# How to make Xcode refresh the editor content?

Tags: xcode, svn

I am developing a project with Xcode 4.1 using Subversion through Xcode's built-in source control menu and command line. When reverting/updating the source through command line, I can't get the Xcode editor to show the current version of the source files (as they appear in the Finder or any external editor). I guess this is generally the case when editing a source file with an external editor.

Eclipse would immediately warn you that the editor content is outdated (Xcode does it when you try to save the file). Then you would simply right click on the project tree to refresh the corresponding files/directories. There must be a similar feature in Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn revert MyFile.m`

will copy the old back and therefore also the old timestamp, making XCode think it is using the most recent version of the file (which is true, except that in this particular situation you would want it to use the older version again).

As a workaround you can "touch" all the reverted files, giving them a new timestamp.

`touch MyFile.m`

That will make XCode display the content as it is in the file and also include it in the next build iteration. This works for .h/.m files but also any project or meta data files used by XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Menue:File >> Source Control >> Refresh Status ?

Comment: That was one of my first guesses, it does refresh the svn status of the file in the project navigator, but the editor content remains the same. To reproduce, add a line to main.m in the editor >> type "svn revert main.m" on the command line >> go back to the editor. The file is no longer considered modified by XCode, but the editor still shows the line of code you added.